# How to find whether app is running in background or foreground or killed android

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I need a suggestion from you guyzz that, In my application i am using **GCM Broadcast receiver** , and my app is having **PIN page** also. Here i need to check a condition like either user is logged in or not when ever push notification comes, depends upon i need to set different  **Activities** . So can anybody suggest me how to solve this?? sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as followed:

When your app is not started/ running and you start from an notification, onCreate gets called.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

When your app is running (background or foreground), and you start a new intent from an notification this method gets called: (if you are using singleTop)

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent){

}
```

To detect whether your app is running back- or foreground, you can simply set a boolean in onPause/onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  runningOnBackground = false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  runningOnBackground = true;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your comment but i have a doubt if user closed from background who it will capture the status? and one more thing. Do i need to write this code on every activity ?

Comment: I don't understand what you means with: _i have a doubt if user closed from background who it will capture the status?_, Yes you need to write this code for every activity.